# How to check if Google Font is properly embedded if I have the font on my computer?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using Google Fonts to use the Open Sans font on a webpage I'm creating, since unfortunately it's not a standard font that everyone has.

However, since I use Open Sans a lot in design work etc, I personally have it installed on my own computer. As such, I don't see any difference after I've added the *link href=...* code, and so I don't know whether or not there's any problem with the code.

Is there any way to see whether things look ok without uninstalling the font from my computer? (once or twice isn't an issue obviously, but I've come across this problem multiple times now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Fonts always tries to use a locally installed font first. One option is include their `@font-face` in your own CSS and remove the `local()` stuff, as explained in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420155/locally-installed-ttf-overrides-google-fonts).